# How can we load secret environmental variables throught AWS Secret Manager in Next.js 13?

Tags: next.js, aws-secrets-manager, next.js13

How can we load secret environmental variables throught AWS Secret Manager in Next.js 13?
It seems there is no guide in Next.js 13 until now. I think if we can call some function in initial building time, we can set that envs through the function. However, I don't find the solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

To load secret environmental variables through AWS Secret Manager in Next.js 13, you can follow these general steps:

1. Set up an AWS account and create a secret in the AWS Secrets Manager. For example, let's say you create a secret with a name "my-secret" and a key "MY_SECRET_KEY".
2. Install the AWS SDK for JavaScript in your Next.js project. You can install it by running the following command in your project's root directory:

```
npm install aws-sdk
```

3. Create a new file called `aws-config.js` in your Next.js project and add the following code:

```js
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';

const client = new AWS.SecretsManager({
  region: 'your-region',
});

export async function getSecret() {
  const { SecretString } = await client.getSecretValue({
    SecretId: 'my-secret',
  }).promise();

  return SecretString;
}
```

Replace `'your-region'` with the AWS region where your secret is stored. This code exports a function `getSecret()` that retrieves the secret value from AWS Secrets Manager.

4. In your Next.js page or API route, import the `getSecret()` function from `aws-config.js` and use it to retrieve the secret value:

```js
import { getSecret } from '../path/to/aws-config';

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const secret = await getSecret();
  const secretValue = JSON.parse(secret)[process.env.MY_SECRET_KEY];
  
  return {
    props: {
      secretValue,
    },
  };
}
```

This code retrieves the secret value from AWS Secrets Manager, parses the JSON string, and retrieves the value associated with the environment variable key `MY_SECRET_KEY`. Finally, it passes the secret value as a prop to the component.

Note that this example assumes that you have already set up the `MY_SECRET_KEY` environment variable in your Next.js project. If you haven't, you can set it up in the `.env.local` file:

```
MY_SECRET_KEY=my-secret-key
```

Make sure to replace `my-secret-key` with the actual key you used when creating the secret in AWS Secrets Manager.

Comment: I see aws-config is the way. I will try to use it in Next.js v13. Thank you.

Comment: Wouldn't this make a call out to SSM on page load? You'd run into rate limits